# Magento 1.9 RWD new-order e-mail broken table

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, order-email

Look at my attachment. This is how my new-order e-mail looks like? Look at the bottom. What's happening with the totals table?

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: Hi Meez, can you post the html of the email in pastebin.com or something? Also, are you using modified email templates? For example by installing `Ho_NL`

Comment: @Sander Mangel Here is the [HTML file](http://pastebin.com/e85dAfR4). Yes i installed Dutch language pack including sale email templates

Comment: I compared the one from Ho_NL and Magento default one is different! So is it better to delete all Ho_NL email templates and do one of the following:
1) system > Transactional Emails > add here all my emails for the appropriate language (i have 5 languages, also Chinese and Japanese)

or

2) Copy all original email template files from `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/` and put in the right language? What is the best workflow?

Comment: I you can afford the time yes, translating them yourself would be better so they are also responsive. But first try one to see if it works :)